SQLModel in FastAPI : NoForeignKeysError
I separately created a Postgresql database with a schema named "geog" and two tables named projections (id, epsg_code, unit_id) and units (id, name).
So in my code I have:

units.py

...
class Unit(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "units"
    metadata = {schema="geog"}

    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    name: str
    projections: List["Projection"] = Relationship(back_populates="units")


projections.py

...
class Projections(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "projections"
    metadata = {schema="geog"}

    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    epsg_code: str
    unit_id: int = Field(foreign_key="units.id")
    unit: Optional["Unit"] = Relationship(back_populates="projections")

And in the DB I manually declared:

in the units table:

pk_units as a pk related to the units.id col


in the projections table:

pk_projections as a pk related to the projections.id col
fk_projections_units_unit_id as a fk related to the projections.unit_id and units.id



But each time I use my CRUD (whatever the function), I've got the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Projection.units - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

UPDATE
The fact is that everything is working fine when I group the different model in a single file. But when I have units.py and projections.py, the join isn't recognized. I'm following the doc about code structure using TYPE_CHECKING but still not work.

You have an error. Projections table cannot have an array relationship to its parent as you're using the singular field unit_id.  For many-to-many relationship you need a pivot table.
So, in order to fix this, the last row of a Projections class should be:
unit: Unit | None = Relationship(back_populates="projections")

and you should change in Unit class:
projections: List["Projection"] = Relationship(back_populates="unit")


Oh sorry if it wasn't clear but it's a many to one relation.
A projection can have only one unit and a unit can be related to 0 or N projections.

The changes that I've written should be doing that - as you can see, in Projections, there is just only one unit. If you want, I can change the answer to have the whole code.

It's just a typo, no? It seems to me that it doesn't change anything about the nature of the relationship, right? Maybe you should edit your answer with the full code to be sure.

So I modified the key "units" to "unit" in the Projection class but not "units" in the projections key of the Unit class because the back_populates argument is related to the DB table and my table is named units. But the fact is that it still doesn't work (but I guess my code is more logic right now)
